# presentModalViewController not working in ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, view, controller

Here I'd my code:

**.h**

```
IBOutlet SecController *SecContr;
```

**.m**

```
[self presentModalViewController:SecContr animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The view controller is presented, but its view is not shown. How can I fix this? By the way I typed this on my phone. Also the iboutlet is definitely connected.

Comment: you should probably not just `init`, but `initWithNibName:bundle:` the `SecContr`.

Comment: I updated my code sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even creating an IBOutlet? You can use this code:

```
(IBAction)presentNextView:(id)sender
{
    SecController *secCont = [[SecController alloc]init];
    secCont.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:secCont animated:YES];
    [secCont release];
}
```

and then hook this up to a button, and you're good to go!

Comment: There are lots of ways to obtain a reference to a view controller instance. Instantiating it directly in code, as you do here, is certainly one way. But it is not the only way; it is also possible to load it from a nib and refer to it by way of an outlet, and in many situations that's a better way.

Comment: I just learned that you can't call presentModalViewController from viewDidLoad and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `presentmodalviewcontroller:animated:completion:`.

You're thinking either of:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

or it's replacement:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The view controller is presented, but its view is not shown

Then your whole question is irrelevantly titled and incorrectly explained. This has nothing whatever to do with how you present the view controller. It has to do with how the view controller obtains its view. You need to set up the relationship between the SecController class and its view. If a view controller can't find its view, it puts up an empty view; that sounds like what you're seeing.

Comment: I should probably mention that I've written an extensive discussion on the topic of how a view controller obtains its view, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_view_controller_and_view_creation